# How can I process BufferedImage faster

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

I'm making a basic image editor to improve my image process skills. I have 12 filters(for now). 
[All filters have a clickable JLabel that has image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWhV3.png)
I update images of all of them when all filters apply with this function:

```
public static void buttonImagesUpdater(){
    for(int i = 0; i < effects.size(); i++){
        effects.get(i).getButton().setImage(new ImageIcon(effects.get(i).process(image)));
    }
}
```

All filters have a process function like that:

```
public BufferedImage process(BufferedImage base) {
    BufferedImage product = new BufferedImage(base.getWidth(), base.getHeight(), base.getType());
    for(int indisY = 0; indisY < base.getHeight(); indisY++){
        for(int indisX = 0; indisX < base.getWidth(); indisX++){
            Color currentColor = new Color(base.getRGB(indisX, indisY));
            int greyTone = 0;
            greyTone = (int) (currentColor.getRed()*0.315) +
                    (int) (currentColor.getGreen()*0.215) 
                    + (int) (currentColor.getBlue()*0.111);
            product.setRGB(indisX, indisY, new Color(greyTone,greyTone,greyTone).getRGB());

        }
    }
    return product;
}
```

Program works so slowly. When I click an effect's button it done 45 second later when I use 5000x3000 image. How can I fix this performance problem?

Comment: * click an effect's button it done 45 second later* Can you provide a [mre] that demonstrates that problem?  Is the one in your question a viable option?

Comment: You can probably speed things up. In your example, stop using `get/setRGB` and creating new `Color` objects in your loop. Avoid floating point arithmetic. But the most important thing to do, is doing things off the EDT (or "in the background"), on a separate thread. Use a `SwingWorker` or similar. This will make your editor *appear* more responsive, which in many cases is more important than the raw performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have got to remember that 3000 * 5000 is 15,000,000 so you're creating 15,000,000 Color objects, you're calling setRGB 15,000,000 times. If I were you, I would look into potentially using ForkJoinPool for this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jason - the problem is that you're creating (and destroying) 15 million Color objects.

However, I don't think that just using multiple threads is going to get you enough of a performance increase, because you are still going to be putting a lot of pressure on memory and the garbage collector, since you'll still be creating and destroying 15 million objects, you'll just be doing several in parallel.

I think that you can both stay away from creating Color objects entirely, and make fewer loops, by using the result of the `BufferedImage` class' `getRGB()` method directly, instead of creating a Color object. Further, you can use the overload of `getRGB()` that returns an array of ints, to get, say, a row of pixels (or more) at a time, to reduce the number of calls that you have to make inside the loop. You can similarly use the version of `setRGB()` that takes an array of pixel values.

The trick is to be able to convert the int color value to a gray value (or whatever else you need to do) without separating the R, G, and B values, or finding an efficient way to separate R, G, and B - more efficient than creating, using, and destroying a Color object.

For a lead on getting R, G, and B values from the int returned by getRGB(), note that the documentation for `Color.getRGB()` says,

> "Returns the RGB value representing the color in the default sRGB
>   ColorModel. (Bits 24-31 are alpha, 16-23 are red, 8-15 are green, 0-7
>   are blue)."

Once you have that working, you can think about parallelizing it.

Comment: I can't understand this overloaded function can you write as so pseudo?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this to see if things speed up a little.

- This uses a DataBuffer from an Image Raster.
- And uses a map to retain previous converted colors.  It may help over a period of time depending on the type of image.
- And works with doubles since the data buffer supports various types.

I also multiplied your values by powers of 2 to shift them in the proper position. The get* methods of Color return values between 0 and 255 inclusive.  The RGB occupy lower 24 bits on an int (Alpha is in the left most byte).

All I see is a dark image but I tested this with other parameters and I know it works.  The long pole in the tent seems to be reading and writing the images.  I was using a `6637 3787` image and could read, alter, and write it in 12 seconds.  For more advanced processing you may want to check on `AffineTransformOp`.

```
    static Map<Color, Double> colorMap = new HashMap<>();

    public BufferedImage process(BufferedImage base) {
        DataBuffer db = base.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < db.getSize(); i++) {
            Color currentColor = new Color(db.getElem(i));
            double greyTone = colorMap.computeIfAbsent(currentColor, v-> 
            currentColor.getRed() * .315 *256*256
                        + currentColor.getGreen() *.215 * 256
                            + currentColor.getBlue()*.115);

            db.setElemDouble(i, greyTone);

        }
        return base;    
    }
```